# Web.config URL rewriter

Tags: c#, web-config

I would like to redirect my logon page to https, but i don't understand why my rules doesn't work, somebody have idea ?

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="http://([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+).<mydomaine>.fr(/logon.html)?" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
</rewrite>
```

when i navigate on the url without https protocol the rule doesn't execute redirect

Comment: everything looks good to me, are you sure the match url is OK?

Comment: what happens when you try it with <match url="(.*)" />

Comment: @DylanSlabbinck it's work.

Answer (score 0):

the good match is : `([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)(.<mydomaine>.fr)(/logon.html)?`